# Ошибка TemplateDoesNotExist Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Я попробовал загрузить страницу  127.0.0.1:8000/contact/ и в консоли появилась ошибка

```
Internal Server Error: /contact/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xsestech/Sites/lessons/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/xsestech/Sites/lessons/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/xsestech/Sites/lessons/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/xsestech/Sites/lessons/mainapp/views.py", line 7, in contact
    return render(request, 'mainapp/basic.html',{'values':['Если у вас остались вопросы, то звоните', 'X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX']})
  File "/Users/xsestech/Sites/lessons/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/xsestech/Sites/lessons/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/Users/xsestech/Sites/lessons/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: mainapp/basic.html
[17/Jul/2018 10:18:28] "GET /contact/ HTTP/1.1" 500 76735
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    re_path(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'mainapp/home.html', )
def contact(request):
      return render(request, 'mainapp/basic.html',{'values':['Если у вас остались вопросы, то звоните', 'X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX']})
```

basic.html

```
{% extends 'mainapp/wrapper.html' %}
{% block content %}
    {% for val in values %}
       <p>{{ val }}</p>

    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

wrapper.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Заголовок страницы</title>
   {% load staticfiles %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css">
  </head>
   <body>
      <div class="jumbotron">
       <div class="container">
       <h1>{% include "mainApp/includes/html.html" %}</h1>
       {% block content %}
       {% endblock %}
       <p>
          <a href="/" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Главная страница</a>
          <a href="/news" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Новости &raquo;</a>
          <a href="/contact" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Контакты</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
        <div class="container">
        <img src="{% static 'mainApp/image/mercedes.png' %}" class="img-   thumbnail">
        <hr>
        &copy; Все права защищены 2018
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

settings.py

```
  """
Django settings for lessons project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '^34_bmos8r3@0@s3vjs)1_)c^zwmck#al)i@piu8lxjr(1u2n&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'webexample',
    'mainapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'lessons.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'lessons.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```

Comment: В settings.py ведь должен быть TEMPLATE_DIRS?

Comment: Вопрос не в том, что находится в basic.html, а где он находится

Comment: basic.html находится в папке /папка-проекта/templates/mainapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'mainapp/home.html', )
def contact(request):
      return render(request, 'mainapp/basic.html',{'values':['Если у вас остались вопросы, то звоните', 'X(XXX)XXX-XX-XX']})
```

Ответ:
Все очень просто, в языке пайтон используются отступы (четыре пробела) которые нужно соблюдать и следить, чтобы они не были нарушены!

```
def index(request):
    return render.....
```

здесь у вас правильный отступ в четыре пробела

```
def contact(request):
      return render....
```

а здесь у вас ВОСЕМЬ пробелов (смотри слово return с разным отступом)